# How change an object reference on run time (Design Patterns)

Tags: java, design-patterns

The application is a text based Starbucks simulator.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFbuI.jpg)

The problem I am facing is how do I change reference to a screen base on a `(x, y)` values.

**I am looking for a solution where I give the screen the responsibility of changing to the next screen base on x and y values.**

Here is the third layer of the application which initial's screen is `MyCards`:

```
public class Frame implements IFrame {

     private IScreen current = new MyCards();

     /* Most code are taken out because not relevant */

     public void touch(int x, int y){ 
         if(current!= null){ current.touch(x, y)}

     }

}
```

If I call `frame.touch(3,3)` it should change the reference to a new screen which I call `MyCardsPay`.

Here is my `interface` I call `IScreen`:

```
public interface IScreen
{

    void touch(int x, int y) ;              // send touch events to screen
    String display() ;                      // displays screen components
    String name() ;                         // returns name of screen
    void next() ;                           // navigate to next screen
    void prev() ;                           // navigate to previous screen
    void setNext(IScreen s, String n ) ;    // set next screen with action name
    void setPrev(IScreen s, String n ) ;    // set previous screen with action name

}
```

Here is my base class I call `Screen`:

```
public class Screen implements IScreen {


    public Screen(){

    }

    @Override
    public void touch(int x, int y) {

    }

    @Override
    public void next() {
        // add code here

    }

    @Override
    public void prev() {
        // add code here
    }

    @Override
    public void setNext(IScreen s, String n ) {
        // add code here 
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrev(IScreen s, String n )  {
        // add code here
    }    


    @Override
    public String display() { 
        return ""; 
    }


    @Override
    public String name() {
        return (this.getClass().getName()).split("\\.")[1] ; 
    }

}
```

Here is my `MyCard` class:

```
public class MyCards extends Screen {

    private Double price;

    public MyCards() {

    }

    public void setPrice(Double p){
        price = p;
    }

    @Override
    public String display(){
        return getPriceDescription() + super.display();
    }

    public String getPriceDescription(){
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return formatter.format(price);
    }
}
```

Here is my `MyCardsPay` class:

```
public class MyCardsPay extends Screen
{

    String cardID;

    public MyCardsPay()
    {

    }

    public void setCardID(String c){
        cardID = c;
    }

    @Override
    public String display(){
        if(cardID == null){
            return super.display();
        }
        return "[" + cardID + "]" + "\n\n\n" + "Scan Now";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not getting wrong, you are storing the current screen by the `current` filed of `Frame` class, and you want to change the screen reference by `Frame.touch()` method?

In this case I would suggest making `touch`(in `IScreen`, and in `MyCards` and `MyCardsPay`) returning not void, but the "result screen" of `touch()`. And store the result by `Frame.current`.

That is to say, `Frame` like:

```
public class Frame implements IFrame {

     private IScreen current = new MyCards();

     /* Most code are taken out because not relevant */

     public void touch(int x, int y){ 
         if(current!= null){ current = current.touch(x, y)}    
     }    
}
```

And the `Screen`s like:

```
public class MyCards extends Screen {

    @Override
    public IScreen touch(int x, int y) {
        if(isOnThePayButton(x, y)){
            return new MyCardsPay();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to use the **Observer pattern**. Have `Screen` tell `Frame` which screen to update on `touch` method.

Use an `interface` to communicate.

```
public interface IScreenFlowObserver {
    void switched(String screen, String n);
}
```

Have Frame `implement` it.

```
public class Frame implements IFrame, IScreenFlowObserver{

  /* More code*/

    public void switched(String screen, String n){ /* */

    }

}
```

Then change the base class to:

```
  public class Screen implements IScreen{
         IScreenFlowObserver observer; 

         public void setObserver(IScreenFlowObserver o){
              observer = o;
        }

   }
```

Last, have a `ScreenFactory` to create Screens.

With that simple design pattern, `Screen` classes can tell `Frame` who to switch to. This allows let `if statments`.